# Foursquare API request not working once deployed, crossdomain issues?

Tags: actionscript-3, security, api, foursquare

I threw together a simple app in flash ide / as3 that pulls photos from a foursquare location. It works locally but once deployed on the web it does not work. I would guess it's a crossdomain issue but what I've found online (link below) so far doesn't answer my question.
http://groups.google.com/group/foursquare-api/browse_thread/thread/ab963f74fde8ae9f/3e68559966acf7c9

I've checked the local vs network setting.I've read I shouldn't need a crossdomain file on my server.
And I believe I've read that I shouldn't need a php proxy for foursquare like I need with twitter...
Not sure what else it can be.

the box where it says testing should trace the response but it never fills, it's like the call stops dead in its tracks after it hits the crossdomain file on foursquare and I don't even get an error response.  http://physicalgraffitea.com/wp-content/swf/Foursquare-e.swf

Distilled the AS3 down to it's leanest here, sans the ID and Secret.

Any help? Thanks

```
   Security.allowDomain("http://www.foursquare.com"); 
    Security.loadPolicyFile("http://api.foursquare.com/crossdomain.xml"); 

        import flash.net.URLRequest;
        import flash.net.URLLoader;
        import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON;

        var resource = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4b7071c8f964a520d51a2de3/photos?group=venue&limit=6&client_id="+myId+"&client_secret="+mySecret+"&v=20120517";


        var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(resource);
        request.method = URLRequestMethod.GET; 
        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
        loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,onIOError);
        loader.load(request);           

    function onComplete(e:Event):void {
                    var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(e.target);
                    outputtxt.text = loader.data;
                    trace(loader.data);
                    var jsonData:Object = JSON.decode(loader.data)
        }
    function onIOError(e:Event):void {
            var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(e.target);
            outputtxt.text = "error " + loader.data;            
     }
```

Comment: Correct about not needing a crossdomain.xml file on your own server; That would only enable flash apps, served from elsewhere, to perform two-way interactions with your website.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of fussing around the only way I could get it to work is to yes, use a crossdomain proxy php file with the foursquare api.

But that alone didn't solve my problem the swf needed to be referenced with the full http path but without the "www" in the path. "http://mydomain.com/swf/file.swf" 
Not sure why but if you have similar cross domain issues try removing the www too